# Remove "x" number of characters from a string in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df looking like this:

```
a                 b
thisisastring     5
anotherstring     6
thirdstring       7
```

I want to remove characters from the left of the strings in column a based on the number in column b. So I tried:

```
df["a"] = d["a"].str[df["b"]:]
```

But this will result in:

```
a                 b
NaN               5
NaN               6
NaN               7
```

Instead of:

```
a                 b
sastring          5
rstring           6
ring              7
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `zip` with string slice

```
df.a=[x[y:] for x,y in zip(df.a,df.b)]
df
Out[584]: 
          a  b
0  sastring  5
1   rstring  6
2      ring  7
```

Comment: This one is definitely faster when I apply it to my dataset! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `apply`, to apply this row-wise:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.a[x.b:],axis=1)

0    sastring
1     rstring
2        ring
dtype: object
```